# In a Win7 Explorer library how to make each included folder display just like normal folders instead of as large headers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When using libraries in Win7 Explorer and adding multiple folders, by default the subfolders are grouped by included parent folder displayed like large headers with expand/collapse capabilities.

**If possible, how to make each included folder display in the library just like normal folders instead of the large headers?**

Answer (score 0):

Goto 'View' then 'Group By' and change it to (none).

Comment: Worked on mine, but now i can't change it back! What's the default anyone? :)

Comment: That just removes the headers and juxtaposes the subfolders of each parent folder. This is not what I'm after. I'm looking for a folder view of the parent folders (in which their subfolders aren't initially visible).

Comment: Btw, to revert your settings, right-click in the library, select Group By -> More... -> Folder name (or what it's called in English).

Comment: Goto Libraries and right click 'Pictures', then 'Properties' - it displays all the locations used?